# How long will Mariadb automatic close the sleep connection

Tags: mariadb

**Update:**
I forgot to set `wait_timeout` in `my.cnf`.

---

I have a persistent connection from my PHP application.
I set the `wait_timeout` to 600 already.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 600   |
+---------------+-------+
```

But the connection doesn't be killed automatically when the sleep time over 600 seconds.
Why?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             | Progress |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
| 32 | lin  | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |    0.000 |
| 33 | lin  | localhost | test | Sleep   |  741 |          | NULL             |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Have you executed any just queries from the same connection in between?

Comment: Remember, this is not on the query but the connection

Answer (score 1):

### wait_timeout

https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/wait_timeout/

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before closing it

Any kind of activity or query, will keep the connection open. My guess is that you run other queries during that time.

### max_statement_time

This is your per query time

> Description: Maximum time in seconds that a query can execute before being aborted. This includes all queries, not just SELECT statements, but excludes statements in stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks, I found the reason. I just forget to set the `wait_timeout` in `my.cnf`.